# Add a point to list of points and rerender on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

So basically what I'm trying to do is let the user double click on the map and create a new point with some info. When they click submit the point should then be added to the state (or later on a database) and then the map rerenders with the correct info. This is what I have so far, where am I going wrong:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMapEvents, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import CovidPoint from './CovidPoint';
import LocationMarkers from './LocationMarkers';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      map: null,
      points: [<CovidPoint
      position={[43.653226, -79.3831843]}
      name="point1"
      information="random point"
      input = {false}
    ></CovidPoint>,
    <CovidPoint
      position={[50.653226, -79.3831843]}
      name="point2"
      information="random point"
      input = {true}
    ></CovidPoint>]
    }
  }

  changePos = (pos, zoom) => {
    const {map} = this.state;
    if (map) map.flyTo(pos, zoom);
  }

  fetchPoints = (newPoints) => {
    this.setState({points: newPoints})
    this.state.points.length > 0 && this.state.points.map(
      (point) => {
        return point
      }
      ) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="title">
          <h1>CovidStopSpots</h1>
          <p>A responsive tracker for Covid-19.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
          <MapContainer
            id="1"
            center={[43.653226, -79.3831843]}
            zoom={13}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            whenCreated={(map) => this.setState({ map })}
            style={{ height: "100vh " }}
          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {this.state.points.length > 0 && this.state.points.map(
      (point) => {
        return point
      }) }
            {/* <CovidPoint
              position={[43.653226, -79.3831843]}
              name="point1"
              information="random point"
            ></CovidPoint>
            <CovidPoint
              position={[50.653226, -79.3831843]}
              name="point2"
              information="random point"
            ></CovidPoint> */}
            <LocationMarkers points={this.state.points} fetchPoints={this.fetchPoints}></LocationMarkers>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

LocationMarkers.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import CovidPoint from "./CovidPoint";

function LocationMarkers(props) {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([]);
  useMapEvents({
    dblclick(ev) {
      console.log("double clicked");
      const { lat, lng } = ev.latlng;
      setPosition([lat, lng]);
      const newPoints = [...props.points];
      console.log(newPoints);
      newPoints.push(<CovidPoint position={position} input={true}></CovidPoint>);
      props.fetchPoints(newPoints);
    }
  });

  return null;

}

export default LocationMarkers;
```

CovidPoint.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import { ChakraProvider, Button, Input} from "@chakra-ui/react";

class CovidPoint extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      position: this.props.position,
      name: this.props.name,
      input: this.props.input,
      information: this.props.information,
      key: this.props.key
    };
  }

  pushPoint(name, info){
    //push to the database
    console.log("pushed to db", name, info)
    this.setState({input: false})
  }

  GetType = (icon) => {
    if (this.state.input === true){
      return (
        console.log("input point"),
        <Marker position={this.state.position} icon={icon}>
            <Popup>
              Name: <Input size="sm" variant="outline" placeholder="Name" onChange={ev => {this.setState({name: ev.target.value})}}/> <br />
              Case Status: <Input size="sm" variant="outline" placeholder="Case Status"  onChange={ev => {this.setState({information: ev.target.value})}}/> <br />
              <Button size = "xs" variant="solid" colorScheme="twitter" onClick={ev => {
                if (this.state.name != "" && this.state.information != ""){
                  this.pushPoint(this.state.name, this.state.information);
                }}}> Submit </Button>
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
      )
    }
    return (
      console.log("normal point"),
      <Marker position={this.props.position} icon={icon}>
            <Popup>
              Name: {this.state.name} <br />
              position: {this.state.position} <br />
              Case Status: {this.state.information}
            </Popup>
      </Marker>
    )
    
  }

  render() {
    const covidIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Redpoint.svg/768px-Redpoint.svg.png",

      iconSize: [30, 30], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor: [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
      popupAnchor: [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });

    return (
      <ChakraProvider>
        <div>
        {this.GetType(covidIcon)}
        </div>
      </ChakraProvider>
      
    );
  }
}

export default CovidPoint;
```

Also the current error I am getting is the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null`, and it happens when I double click on the map. No idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are creating an array of JSX elements which makes things unnecessarily complicated in my opinion. Actually it is much simpler than it sounds in the first place.

You want to store information regarding locations using their popup.
So your data will be

1. latlng
2. name
3. case status

Your data should be an array of objects containing the 3 mentioned properties

You can even start from a couple of dummy data as you have in your example. The initial status of locations should be similar to locations var below.

```
function LocationMarkers() {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState(
    [
      {
        latlng: [43.653226, -79.3831843],
        name: "point1",
        caseStatus: "random point1"
      }
    ],
    {
      latlng: [50.653226, -79.3831843],
      name: "point2",
      caseStatus: "random point2"
    }
  );

  useMapEvents({
    dblclick(ev) {
       const { lat, lng } = ev.latlng;
       const newLocations = [...locations];
       newLocations.push({ latlng: [lat, lng], name: "", caseStatus: "" });
       setLocations(newLocations);
    }
  });

  return <CovidPoint locations={locations} setLocations={setLocations} />;
}
```

- Every time you add a point on the map your are pushing to the locations array a new location object containing the coordinates in the beginning and hosting the other properties you want to add later.
- Pass locations and setLocations as props to CovidPoint to be able to add, edit name and case status from there using the locations index.
- Then in your CovidPoint comp you don't need any state.

  ```
   const { locations, setLocations } = this.props;

   return (
     locations.length > 0 &&
     locations.map(({ latlng, name, caseStatus }, index) => (
       <Marker position={latlng} icon={covidIcon} key={index}>
         <Popup>
           Name:
           <input
             placeholder="Name"
             value={name}
             onChange={(e) => {
               const newLocations = [...locations];
               const newLocationObj = { ...newLocations[index] };
               newLocationObj.name = e.target.value;
               newLocations[index] = newLocationObj;
               setLocations(newLocations);
             }}
           />
           <br />
           <br />
           Case Status:
           <input
             value={caseStatus}
             placeholder="Case Status"
             onChange={(e) => {
               const newLocations = [...locations];
               const newLocationObj = { ...newLocations[index] };
               newLocationObj.caseStatus = e.target.value;
               newLocations[index] = newLocationObj;
               setLocations(newLocations);
             }}
           />
         </Popup>
       </Marker>
     ))
   );
  ```

You don't even need a Submit button to change the state locally. You will only need it if you want to make api calls to save, edit or delete the data in the db.
Now once you add a point on the map, you click on the point and you have the popup with the info and be able to add / change them

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-a-point-to-list-of-points-with-additional-data-and-rerender-on-map-in-react-leaflet-v3x-8un02?file=/src/CovidPoint.jsx:366-1355)

Comment: Thanks man, you are a legend. There is one small issue here, I want once the user presses submit, to make that into a "real" point on the database, and make the point read only. Hence, I think I will need to render 2 versions on the point, one that accepts input, and one that is just readable. My current implementation does this (I think) but the issue occurs when I double click on the map, it says `can't read property lat of null`

Comment: No problem. I fixed a bug with object cloning when updating name and case status in the locations array of objects. in React when you copy the state in order to update it you need to clone first the array and then the object otherwise you can end up with unpredicted state. Regarding your question try disabling the current inputs when saving to the db after pressing submit. Why rendering the same point twice?

Comment: how would i disable current inputs though?

Comment: It is simple. When you send the request you will receive an id from the db. After receiving the id you will update your location object with that id. If the id exists then you will disable the inputs of a specific location point